# AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU coun / Problem loading X.509 certificate -65

Tags: linux, x509, linux-mint, amd-processor

Computer:

- Lenovo Ideapad S145,
- AMD Ryzen 5 3500u.
- SSD 120gb(SO) + hd1t

I recently installed Linux Mint on my computer. And these errors have appeared when starting. When these errors appear and turn on, and at other times these errors appear and go to a black screen.

Please, does anyone know why?

[image: error-everytimes]

[image: error-sometimes]

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 13):

I'm running debian on my laptop Lenovo XiaoXin pro13 (Ideapad s540 13) AMD ryzen 4800u, and encounter the same issues.

I fixed the " AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter"  by editing the grub config file at /etc/default/grub and added

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"
```

and update grub config by execute

```
sudo update-grub
```

To fix another error just go into your laptop bios, disable the
Secure Boot and Reset it to Setup Mode

Comment: what if I have live-iso and I cannot directly manipulate the `/etc/default/grub` (do not even have that file)? What shoudl I do then?

Comment: this helped me with Ubuntu w. Kernel 5.8 on my Ryzen 7 4750U. Thanks!